# YouTube Search Error "Google Sorry... We're sorry... ... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries"

Tags: search, browser, youtube

I have developed Web Browser in VB.Net 2008 and upgrade to visual studio 2013. Before upgrade Web Browser works 100% but after upgrade the error come with something searching in Youtube as below.

*https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cricket+highlights*

Google Sorry...

**We're sorry...
... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.
See Google Help for more information.**

Youtube search results are working fine in Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, but not work in my web browser.

How to fix this i am stuck this point.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heVFR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution.............

The Web Browser Control is - by default - perpetually stuck in IE 7 rendering mode. Even though we're now up to IE 11 and a reasonably HTML5 compatible browser, the Web Browser Control always uses the IE 7 rendering engine by default. This is because the original versions of the ActiveX control used this mode and for backwards compatibility the Control continues this outdated and very HTML5 unfriendly default.

This applies whether you’re using the Web Browser control in a WPF application, a WinForms app using the ActiveX control. Behind the scenes all these UI platforms use the same COM interfaces and so you’re stuck with those same rules.

The good news is there are a couple of ways to override the default rendering behavior:

- Using the IE X-UA-Compatible Meta header Using Application specific
- FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Registry Keys

HTML fix;

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
    ... other headers
  </head>
  <body>
    ... content
  </body>
</html>
```

Via registry;

Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION for 64-bit or 32-bit only machines.

Or go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION for 32-bit on 64-bit systems (It cannot hurt to add keys to both locations if you have them. If you do not have them, you can make the folders yourself).

Create a new DWORD key and name it the name of your application e.g. "myapp.exe" and then edit the value of the key. There are many different values you can add depending on the IE version you want to emulate. I entered 11001 (as a decimal value - 0x2AF9 in HEX) which emulates IE 11 (many more values located at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation).

If you're using Visual Studio like I am, you'll notice that this method might not even work. However, it does work. You need to manually open the .exe file using Explorer or terminal rather than run the project on Visual Studio.

If you wish to run the program on Visual Studio then consider adding a key for "myapp.vshost.exe" as this is used for debugging.

I hope this helps anyone with any issue regarding your Web Browser perhaps using the wrong IE version as a wrapper or functions are not working as intended.

Comment: Can you confirm these solutions actually work for you?  Or did you have to take additional steps not mentioned here? I'm still getting the error message, on Windows 10.